# Using Javascript to convert ? in URL to anchor

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, anchor

How can I convert this:

http://example.com/?thisurl

to this:

http://example.com/#/thisurl

I have a bunch of old URLs that need to redirect to specific anchors on my page but I can't do it with htaccess because the anchors don't get passed through.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '#/' +
                       window.location.search.replace(/^?/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.hash` and `.search` parts of the `window.location` object like this:

```
window.location.hash = "/" + window.location.search.substr(1);
```

This will set the hash without reloading the page.

---

If you want to reload the page so it has a new URL (without the `?thisUrl` in the URL bar, then you could do this:

```
var wl = window.location;
if (wl.search.length > 1) {
    wl.href = wl.href.replace(/\?.*$/, "") + "#" + wl.search.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: The first script works! Is there a way to write the URL so I get domain.com/#myurl instead of domain.com/?myurl#myurl ?

Comment: @user1738343 - then use the first version if it doesn't have the problem..  We can't help with the redirect problem from your other javascript because you haven't disclosed that other code.  That other code could be coded to NOT do the redirect if there's a hash present.

Comment: Sorry, see my edited post above—the first script does indeed work.

Comment: If you want it to work in all browsers, then changing the URL (other than setting `window.location.hash`) will cause a page reload.  If you only want it to work in modern browsers, you can use `window.history.replaceState()` to change what shows in the URL bar without reloading the page.  See [MDN doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) on `replaceState()`.